# Elastic Beanstalk with git submodules - deployed code has no execute permissions

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, git-submodules

I Use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Python Django application over AWS Linux 2 machine. My git project includes another git repository integrated as git submodule.

I followed [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html) instructions.

Specifically I configured:

.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml:

```
global:
  branch: main
  include_git_submodules: true
```

.gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "MyFamousSubmodule"]
    path = MyFamousSubmodule
    url = https://github.com/hoshmy/MyFamousSubmodule.git
    auto-update=yes
    branch=main
```

Once I *eb deploy* the whole git repo including the submodule files are deployed successfully to the machine and are visible under /var/app/current.
Testing the application throws exception indicating that a certain python module (py file) isn't available. I *eb ssh* to the machine and discovered that the whole submodules python files don't have execute permissions (-rw------- ).

Other py files, not under the submodule, has appropriate executable permissions (-rwxr-xr-x)

**My Question**: How to properly set/configure the submodule within the repo and/or the eb for proper deployment?

Comment: The `submodule.<name>.auto-update` setting does not seem to mean anything. What do you expect it to do? (This is probably not related to your problem, it just stands out as an oddity.)

Answer (score 0):

You can clone separately the submodule on your computer to confirm the `py` files don't have execute permissions.

If so, and assuming you can contribute to the repository, add them with:

```
git add --chmod=+x *.py
git commit -m "Add execution permission to py files"
git push
```

From there, try your `eb deploy` once more.

Comment: Thank you VonC for you answer.
I tried that - and even edited the command to perform recursively - due to my folders structure:

`find -name '*.py' -exec git add --chmod+x {} +`

Unfortunately this didn't had any effect on the deployed files.

Out of frustration I created a flat copy of my repo - and converted the submodule to a regular committed folder - and the deployment is perfect.

Comment: @hoshmy Actually, I forgot that, for submodule files, you must add, commit and push, and then go to the parent folder, add commit and push (to record the new submodule state)